# ngClick is not working on a div element

Tags: angularjs

I've been stuck at this for a while, this is my generated html:

```
<div style="margin: 0 5px; border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; height:24px;">
   <div id="activity-bar" class="padding0 margin0 ng-isolate-scope" style="width: 100%; background: rgb(179, 179, 179); position: relative; overflow: visible; height: 20px;" ng-style="thisStyle" display-sections="student.history_list" height="20" loading="loading" type="2" user-id="student.fic_student_id">
     <div ng-click="console.info('working');" class="activity-section absolute-pos inline-block act-29464 task-background-3 ng-scope" style="left:0%; width:10%;height:20px;" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="PrimaryGames: Free Games and Videos
primarygames.com (click on the bar to view)
start time: 09:40am"></div>
    <div ng-click="console.info('working');" class="activity-section absolute-pos inline-block act-54094 task-background-4 ng-scope" style="left:10%; width:10%;height:20px;" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="writing0.sumdog.com
writing0.sumdog.com (click on the bar to view)
start time: 09:45am"></div>
    <div ng-click="console.info('working');" class="activity-section absolute-pos inline-block act-54094 task-background-4 ng-scope" style="left:20%; width:10.01%;height:20px;" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="writing0.sumdog.com
writing0.sumdog.com (click on the bar to view)
start time: 09:50am"></div>
    <!-- Some more divs -->
   </div>
</div>
```

The tooltips are working but the ng-clicks are not, am i missing something?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @SyamPillai nope, none

Comment: `ng-click` doesn't execute arbitrary JavaScript, it executes functions which are properties of the `$scope` object.  do you have a `$scope.console.info()` in the controller for this HTML segment?

Comment: That explains it, thanks @Claies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular, recommended way is to call function

```
<div ng-click="consoleinfo('working')"
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.consoleinfo = function(message){
console.log(message);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/k89LhOIt3bCWFXvRyxhB?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried putting a function in the scope and call it from there the first time but that didn't work

Comment: ng-click="myFunction()" didn't work, that's why I tried adding in the expression directly in there instead of calling a function but that didn't work as well.

Comment: @NaguibIhab check the demo